# Why doesn't Yuriko get suspicious that a janitor is in a handscan-protected room?

Tags: plot-explanation, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-2

In *X2*, Mystique infiltrates the office of Yuriko to hack into the computers and find the location of Magneto's plastic prison.

In doing so, she gets takes on the appearance of Yuriko and imitates her handscan. However, the real Yuriko, unaware that Mystique is in the room, gets into the room and finds Mystique who now looks like a janitor and replies *"garbage"* when asked by Yuriko what s/he was doing there.

Shouldn't she be suspicious since the room is locked with a handprint-scanner?

Answer (score 3):

### Not necessarily

**Note: She asked "What are you doing here?" *not* "How did you get in here?"**

Garbage doesn't collect itself and it's likely that the janitorial staff would be able to enter offices to clean up...so *their* handprints would be on file and acceptable to the scanner.

Janitors and cleaners often have access to secure areas and go through security vetting procedures as well.

It's the staff in those areas who have the responsibility of making sure that important documents and files are properly secured so they can't be seen by passers-by.

Note though that any unauthorised person in the office *still* can't access any secrets unless they can access the computers...and those are **voiceprint restricted**.

[image]